# Pandas dataframe: add a column by condition on another column -- find the nearest value downward

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 1.434, np.nan, np.nan, 5.466])
```

yields the df

```
       0
0    NaN
1  1.434
2    NaN
3    NaN
4  5.466
```

The critical of the new added column '1': assign the 'NaN' in column '0' to the nearest downward value.

```
       0      1
0    NaN  1.434
1  1.434  1.434
2    NaN  5.466
3    NaN  5.466
4  5.466  5.466
```

Comment: Use `df[1] = df[0].bfill()`